# preg_replace '</p>' with '<br />'?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have my code removing the `<p>` starting tags, but now I want to replace the ending `</p>` tags with line breaks. How can I do this?

This is what I have:

```
$content = 'This is the content';
$newcontent = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>", "", $content);
$newcontent = preg_replace("</p>", "<br />", $newcontent);
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? `<p>` is semantic, while `<br/>` is rarely so.

Comment: Well it's necessary for what I'm doing because I'm actually using this in shortcodes for WordPress, and there's a bug with multiple lines inside the shortcodes and I'm trying to find a workaround for it until they fix it.

Comment: there's also reasons to do this for html email purposes - so it's not that strange a request

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use str_replace instead of preg_replace, so:

```
$content = '<p>This is a new content for missing slash</p>';
$newcontent = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>/", "", $content);
$newcontent = str_replace("</p>", "<br />", $newcontent);
```

Comment: @Jared - if RIMMER's answer solved your problem, you should accept it.

Comment: It told me I had to wait 11 minutes. :P Anyways, is there now a way to replace `</div><br /><br />` with just `</div>` from that string? I know it's a little weird but it's necessary for what I'm working on.

Comment: `$newcontent = str_replace("</div><br /><br />", "</div>", $newcontent);`

Comment: Duh - figured out my problem. :P Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10):

```
$content = preg_replace('#<p(.*?)>(.*?)</p>#is', '$2<br/>', $content);
```