# Changing <p> to <br>

Tags: php

Is it possible to find all `<p>` tabs in a string and replace them with `<br>` tabs?

For example, if I have a string which looks like this:

```
<p>some test here</p>
<p>some more test here</p>
<p>some other test here</p>
```

Is it possible to change it to the following:

```
some test here<br /><br />
some more test here<br /><br />
some other test here<br /><br />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg_replace '</p>' with '<br />'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294209/preg-replace-p-with-br)

Comment: with such a primitive question it never works :) Too much people wants to show their deep knowledge on the matter :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In what language? PHP?

```
$text=str_replace(array('<p>','</p>'),array('','<br /><br />'),$text);
```

Comment: This is the answer. You don't need to wait for marking it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$pattern = '/<p>(.*)<\/p>/';
$replacement = '/${1}<br\/><br\/>/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a regExp replace in NotePad++ :

find :

```
<p>(.*)</p>
```

replace :

```
\1<br /><br />
```

But I advise you to change the `<p>` CSS Class to play with margin-bottom instead of adding `<br>`

```
p {
  margin : 0 0 2em 0;
}
```

Comment: My answer is for a design-time replacement, follow the other answers for a run-time replacement.